# Page numbering style with fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr

I am having some issues with setting my thesis formatting and I may need some assistance with the fancyhdr package.
The problem is, I made by own style from a combination of two templates and there must be some inherited settings from each of them (and each different), but I am unable to locate them. This is what the pages look like: 
[image: An example] [image: of my problem]

As you see, the LEFT pages have the page number as a footer under a line and the RIGHT pages have the page number as a header and with no line. I want to have the chapter name in the headers and page numbers in the footers. 
This is a part of my preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright, english]{book}

% INSTAL THE PACKAGES I WILL MOST LIKELY NEED
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{latexsym, syntonly, textcomp, amsmath, caption, float}
\usepackage{graphicx}%[pdftex]
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}%[outdir=./Figures/]{epspdfconversion}
\usepackage{blindtext, setspace, rotating}
\usepackage{natbib, longtable}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{threeparttable} %for footnote in tables
\usepackage[hyphens]{url} %break line within long url
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage[top=2.3cm, inner=3.2cm, bottom=2.4cm, outer=2.3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}

\usepackage[strings]{underscore}

% LOWER CASE CHAPTER AND SECTION HEADINGS
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
        \markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
        \markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{}  % delete current header and footer
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\bfseries\thepage}
%\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
%\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\emph\textit{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\emph\textit{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}
\fancyhead[RE]{}
\fancyhead[LO]{}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{3pt} % space for the rule
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhead{} % get rid of headers on plain pages
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt} % and the line
        }

\onehalfspacing

\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\clearpage
```

What have I missed? I thought I have all the settings.

Comment: Please post a MWE (minimal working example) instead of just 'part of your preamble'. Did you select your headerstyle with `\thispagestyle{fancy}` by any chance, since only the opening pages have it applied?

Comment: Nope, the only things that I excluded were settings of unrelated things (dedication etc., which had its own `\thispagestyle{empty}`). Otherwise the document begins, that's all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is at least a `\pagestyle{fancy}` missing. The normal pages still use pagestyle `headings`. Note that `\pagestyle{fancy}` must be used at least once before the redefinition of `\chaptermark` and `\sectionmark`, because the first call of `\pagestyle{fancy}` also redefines this commands.

I am not sure about the desired page layout. Maybe

[image]

Code (without all the unrelated stuff):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright,english]{book}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\addtolength{\headheight}{3pt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}% <- must be used before the redefinition of \chaptermark and \sectionmark
% change the marks set by \chapter and \section
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
% change fancy style
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
% change plain style (eg. used on chapter pages)
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % comment this line, if there should be a headsepline on plain pages too
}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}% LoF and LoT should get a ToC entry
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

If there should be a headsepline on plain pages too, remove the change of `\headrulewidth` inside the definition of page style `fancyplain`.

Additional remark: In your code the `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}` and `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}` are at the wrong place. They would add the page numbers of the last pages of LoF and LoT to the table of contents. You could use package `tocbibind` instead.